# The data entered to the postgres db is altered somehow?

Tags: postgresql, openlayers, geoserver

I've created a postgres DB with postgis extension and a table with this command:

```
create table lgeognad33 (ID serial primary key, geom geometry(POLYGON,3857) not null );
```

then created workspace and postgis datastore and published that table as a layer in geoserver...this layer will be used by openlayers client as 'WFS' requests...**the client code is:**

```
var formatWFS = new WFS();

var formatGML = new GML({
  featureNS: 'https://data.drawns.org/',
  featureType: 'lgeognad33',
  srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var sourceWFS = new VectorSource({
  loader: function (extent) {
    $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/SDWS/ows', {
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
      service: 'WFS',
      version: '1.1.0',
      request: 'GetFeature',
      typename: 'lgeognad33',
      srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
     // bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
    }
  }).done(function (response) {
  sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
});
},
//strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()),
strategy: extent,
projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var layerWFS = new VectorLayer({
  source: sourceWFS
});

var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: [],
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }), layerWFS
  ],
  view: new View({
 // center: fromLonLat([-1.7, 53.2]),
  center: [4086950.39, 4127574.58],
  zoom: 6
  })
});

var transactWFS = function (p, f) {
  let node;
  switch (p) {
    case 'insert':
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
      break;
  }

  var s = new XMLSerializer();
  var str = s.serializeToString(node);
  $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/SDWS/lgeognad33/wfs', {
    service: 'WFS',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: str,
  }).done();
}

var interaction;

$('#drawPoly').on('click', function (event) {
  interaction = new Draw({
  type: 'Polygon',
  source: layerWFS.getSource()
  });
  map.addInteraction(interaction);
  interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
  transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
  });
});
```

I expect the data inserted in the db to be in epsg:3857 but the result of any inserted polygon is 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ... i don't know if geoserver is transforming the data or re-projecting it (didn't find any clue why this is happening)...

**the request payload sent from the client is:**

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><Insert><lgeognad33 xmlns="https://data.test.org/"><geometry><Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857"><exterior><LinearRing srsName="EPSG:3857"><posList srsDimension="2">4039544.0708149946 4071341.874581627 4144721.421735397 4034652.1010047426 4012638.236858613 3995516.342522732 4039544.0708149946 4071341.874581627</posList></LinearRing></exterior></Polygon></geometry></lgeognad33></Insert></Transaction>
```

**Note:** the Native SRS and Declared SRS in geoserver are: epsg:3857

**Note:** This is a photo of the table, the only different row is a row I've inserted by my hand and it is rendered correctly in the map, all other rows are different polygons submitted from the client
[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DftZp.png)

**Note:** the transaction request is:

```
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseURL = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:insert=net.opengis.wfs.impl.InsertElementTypeImpl@fa0073 (feature: [SimpleFeatureImpl:lgeognad33=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: geom<geom id=fid--5772524c_1681ace82ae_-7ff7>=POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))]], handle: null, idgen: <unset>, srsName: null)
    insert[0]:
        feature[0] = SimpleFeatureImpl:lgeognad33=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: geom<geom id=fid--5772524c_1681ace82ae_-7ff7>=POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))]
        idgen = GenerateNew
        inputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    releaseAction = ALL
```

Comment: Please add the text of the post xml not a picture

Comment: Then check the log file and add that text to the question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lays in the name of the geometry field in the database, the default name is "geometry" and this is what geoserver understand but when you use another name like "geom" you should use the setGeometryName function of openlayers feature class to set the name of the geometry for your inserted feaure, I did the following to solve the issue:

```
feature.setGeometryName('geom');
transactWFS('insert', feature);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but did you check to see if the layer has "write" access? Under Security, then Data you can add a rule that grants rights to the layer. The layer is usually read only at first so you need to add the "write" authority to it. After adding the new rule I add all the roles except the admin to all my layers that are transactional.

Comment: the problem is within the DB cause the id field is added with each insertion but the geometry field is not...i am going to work more on the problem and then edit the question if I find a more detailed issue... thanks for your attention...

Comment: I had some problems with it too, for me it was a combination of the rule and then on my table I had to manually add CREATE INDEX sidx_wfs_geom
  ON wfs_geom
  USING gist
  (geometry);

Comment: I managed to solve the exception but now the data is altered some how...any idea??

Comment: Altered in what way? The geometry? I have compared your code to mine all the vital parts are the same, so that is probably not the problem, so it is somewhere in geoserver or your database. I can't really help without knowing more.

Comment: yes the geometry field is altered...I've added a picture of the db table...

Comment: what srs do you use in the client, database table and geoserver??

Comment: In geoserver I always use 3857 if my layers aren't already, usually they are. My wfs-t layers in the database either have no srs or 3857. The ones with none I'm exporting them and projecting them in arcmap and importing them into a different database that the public can view. One thing that is different is the geometry column, I don't specify if it is a polygon, point etc.

Comment: One thing that is different is where your request payload says just <Transaction> mine says <wfs:TransactionResponse> when posting and <wfs:FeatureCollection> for the call.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but when using 3857 on client,server and db the posted data enter the db with the same geometry value as the picture shows...when I changed it to 4326 every thing worked correctly...seems like the problem was with geoserver...don't know what it is to submit an answer for the question..!!